# Can we send a class instance to kafka in Python?

Tags: python, serialization, apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

I want to send a class instance to kafka broker.

```
A1 = Axestrack('1087999','2018-05-24')
```

Here Axestrack is a python class and A1 is an instance of class Axestrack.
Now how can I send this instance to kafka broker?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could send it as CSV, JSON, Avro, or encode a `bytes` object yourself.

As long as you can configure a deserializer to read it back out, it doesn't really matter what format you send it.

There is no "built-in" Python-Kafka serializer (except maybe `pickle`)